# C++, инициализация constexpr полей

Tags: c++, c++11, инициализация, constexpr

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли инициализировать `constexpr` член не в хедере, а в файле реализации?

Например:

```
// hpp
class Object
{
    public:
    constexpr size_t VALUE;
};

// cpp
constexpr Object::VALUE = 1U;
```

Если возможно, то как?

Если нет, то почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте подумаем. У вас есть файл, отличный от вашего cpp, в котором написано ваше

```
constexpr Object::VALUE = 1U;
```

Но вы пытаетесь в нем обратиться к этому члену. Это обращение требует знания значения во время компиляции, но *откуда его взять*? Если оно в каком-то третьем файле?

Перерывать все файлы проектов? "Где же логика?!" (с) Анекдот

Comment: Ну я подумал, а вдруг компилятор сможет...

Comment: Что-то не то. Ты, наверное, использование предполагал, а не присваивание?

Answer (score 1):

Нестатические поля класса не могут быть объявлены как `constexpr`. Однако для класса можно делать `constexpr` конструктор, реализацию которого вынести вне определения класса.